# How to remove duplicate data from hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, impala, hbasestorage

I have a hbase table.

Table Schema: empid, empname,age

Data 1: Key - 1001 Value- 1,John,26 (Correct Data)

Data 2: Key - 1002 Value- 1,John,25 (InCorrect Data. By Mistakely entered by user.)

There is only two column has same values which empid, empname. I want to fetch those records which has same value for all column except single column value is different.

**Note: It can be possible 3 column has same value but fourth one has different.**

It would be good if you can give me Impala Query.

Comment: I have created a table in hbase and use group by to find duplicate records. Query is as below:                                                select eid,ename,count(*) from emp_hive_new group by eid,ename but as i said it can be possible that 3 column has same value but fourth one has different. so how could i achieve through impala.

Comment: In that case you can group by on 3 columns..